# Accessing Named Pipe with Simulink?

Tags: simulink, named-pipes

I have a named pipe server in my software, which I have accessed using C# and Python.  I have a customer asking me if it's possible to access the named pipe through Simulink, but I have never used that software.  Google and Stackoverflow don't seem to contain any examples of this, but I'm not sure that means that it's not possible.  Does anyone know for sure whether Simulink is or isn't capable of accessing the named pipe server in another program?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what simulink is, but a named pipe usually just shows up like a file... they would have to go to some length to detect that a file was a pipe (`fstat`/`lstat`)

but you can make one to test with like...

`mkfifo dog`

`echo "bark"`

then try to open that file in simulink...

that is just basically the semantics of opening a file, if simulink tries to seek around in the file ... it will
 fail...

you should read about what a fifo is, and play with it, like in the above example:
try in another shell: `cat dog`...

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Most of my question is about the capabilities of Simulink, however.  Simulink is a product by The Mathworks, who are best known for MATLAB.  While I've written many M-File programs for MATLAB, I've never used Simulink before (it's a graphical interface for MATLAB) so I have little idea what it can do.  I was hoping someone on SO would.  I think I might be able to download a trial version of it long enough to figure out what its capabilities are.